# Merge Word documents does not merge with pictures

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

My code merges multiple Word documents from various folders. It creates a cover page and gradually adds other documents, ensuring that the header and footer from the cover page are inherited in the newly merged Word document.

The issue is that the images from the documents are not being included. I suspect that the code may be treating them as text files or something similar.

How can I fix this?

```
import os
from docx import Document
import shutil

def copy_cover_page(folder_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("_New.docx"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

                # Create a new file name
                new_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "_merged.docx"
                destination_path = os.path.join(root, new_file_name)

                # If a file with "_merged" already exists, replace it
                if os.path.exists(destination_path):
                    os.remove(destination_path)

                # Copy the Word file
                shutil.copy(file_path, destination_path)

def copy_and_merge_documents(folder_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("_New.docx"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

                # Create a new file name
                new_file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "_merged.docx"
                destination_path = os.path.join(root, new_file_name)

                # If a file with "_merged" already exists, open it
                if os.path.exists(destination_path):
                    merged_document = Document(destination_path)
                else:
                    # Otherwise, create a new "_merged" file
                    merged_document = Document()

                # Copy the content of the Word document (cover page)
                shutil.copy(file_path, destination_path)

                # Open the destination document for merging
                target_document = Document(destination_path)

                # Iterate over all paragraphs in the source document and add them to the destination document
                for paragraph in merged_document.paragraphs:
                    text = paragraph.text
                    target_document.add_paragraph(text)

                # Save the updated "_merged" destination document
                target_document.save(destination_path)

                # Iterate over all "_New_X" files up to the highest existing number
                num = 1
                while True:
                    new_x_path = os.path.join(root, file.replace("_New.docx", f"_New_{num}.docx"))
                    if os.path.exists(new_x_path):
                        # Add the "_New_X" file to the destination document
                        append_docx_with_images(target_document, new_x_path)
                        num += 1
                    else:
                        break

                # Add a new page for each inserted file
                target_document.add_page_break()

                # Save the updated "_merged" file
                target_document.save(destination_path)

def append_docx_with_images(doc1, doc2_path):
    """
    Appends the content of doc2 to doc1, including images.
    """
    doc2 = Document(doc2_path)
    for element in doc2.element.body:
        doc1.element.body.append(element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = r"C:\Users\michael.bildeyko\Documents\Tobi Over the Mountain\Word richtig zusammenfügen\Kataloge Kopien"
    copy_cover_page(folder_path)
    copy_and_merge_documents(folder_path)
```